# Issue with the quicksort implementation

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I have the following quicksort implementation derived from the quicksort method taken from GeeksForGeeks. The change from the original version is an attempt for the function to **take the last element as the pivot** and **sort the list from large to small**. However, it did not work as intended.

```
def partition(start, end, array):
      
    # Initializing pivot's index to end
    pivot_index = end 
    pivot = array[pivot_index]

    while start < end:
        while end > -1 and array[end] <= pivot:
            end -= 1
        
        while array[start] > pivot:
            start += 1

        if(start < end):
            array[start], array[end] = array[end], array[start]
      
    array[end], array[pivot_index] = array[pivot_index], array[end]
    return end

def quick_sort(start, end, array):
      
    if (start < end):
        p = partition(start, end, array)
          
        quick_sort(start, p - 1, array)
        quick_sort(p + 1, end, array)
          
        
array = [ 12, 3, 18, 7, 15, 11, 13, 9 ]
quick_sort(0, len(array) - 1, array)

print(f'Sorted array: {array}')
```

This function goes into an infinite loop and I'm unsure what is causing it. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: Use a debugger and compare execution to the original code  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You could help yourself perhaps get an answer if you show in your code as comments exactly what you changed

Comment: First i’d make sure you started from working code by reverting to source and using data that geeksforgeeks shows the sorting for, keep using that data for debugging. Then i’d change _one thing at once_ e.g. first make it sort in reverse order, and make sure it works, then change other things one thing at a time, e,g, choosing the last element as pivot making sure the output is unchanged, … rinse and repeat.